# Can FP compares like SSE2 _mm_cmpeq_pd be used to compare 64 bit integers?

Tags: simd, sse, avx, sse2

Can FP compares like SSE2 `_mm_cmpeq_pd` / AVX `_mm_cmp_pd` be used to compare 64 bit integers?

The idea is to emulate missing `_mm_cmpeq_epi64` that would be similar to `_mm_cmpeq_epi8`, `_mm_cmpeq_epi16`, `_mm_cmpeq_epi32`.

The concern is I'm not sure if the comparison is bitwise, or handles floating point specifically, like NAN values are always unequal.

Comment: Not directly, since `NaN != NaN` and `-0.0 == 0.0`. Probably something is possible with some clever bit-fiddling.

Comment: @chtz, thanks, that's enough for me, you can post this as answer if you like, I wouldn't go into clever bit fiddling, it is easier to do with `_mm_cmpeq_epi32` then.

Comment: I think this should work for any "normal" `c`: `_mm_cmpeq_pd(c, _mm_xor_pd(c, _mm_xor_pd(a,b)));`. Though interestingly, gcc optimizes away the `c` (but you can trick it by mixing the order of the xor operations): https://godbolt.org/z/jraEq9seb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AVX implies availability of SSE4.1 `pcmpeqq` is available, in that case you should just use `_mm_cmpeq_epi64`.

FP compares treat NaN != NaN, and `-0.0 == +0.0`, and if DAZ is set in MXCSR, treat any small integer as zero.  (Because exponent = 0 means it represents a denormal, and Denormals-Are-Zero mode treats them as exactly zero on input to avoid possible speed penalties for any operations on any microarchitecture, including for compares.  IIRC, modern microarchitectures don't have a penalty for subnormal inputs to compares, but do still for some other operations.  In any case, programs built with `-ffast-math` set FTZ and DAZ for the main thread on startup.)

**So FP compares are not really usable for integers unless you know that some but not all of [bits [62:52] (inclusive)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) will be set.**

---

It's much to use `pcmpeqd` (`_mm_cmpeq_epi32`) than to hack up some FP bit-manipulation.  (Although @chtz suggested in comments you could do `42.0 == (42.0 ^ (a^b))` with `xorpd`, as long as the compiler doesn't optimize away the constant and compare against 0.0.  That's a GCC bug without -ffast-math).

If you want a condition like at-least-one-match then you need to make sure both halves of a 64-bit element matched, like `mask & (mask<<1)` on a `movmskps` result, which can compile to `lea` / `test`.  (You could `mask & (mask<<4)` on a `pmovmskb` result, but that's slightly less efficient because LEA copy-and-shift can only shift by 0..3.)

Of course "all-matched" doesn't care about element sizes so you can just use `_mm_movemask_epi8` on any compare result, and check it against `0xFFFF`.

If you want to use it for a blend with and/andnot/or, you can `pshufd` / `pand` to swap halves within 64-bit elements.  (If you were feeding `pblendvb` or `blendvpd`, that would mean SSE4.1 was available so you should have used `pcmpeqq`.)

The more expensive one to emulate is SSE4.2 `pcmpgtq`, although I think GCC and/or clang do know how to emulate it when auto-vectorizing.